# Select attributes in a subregion of a vector layer?

Tags: qgis, sql

I have a QGIS vector layer based on a shapefile.

I would like to select a distinct list of attributes in a subregion of that layer based on the lat/longs of a bounding box. Something like:

`Select Distinct CODE, DESC from mylayer 
Where <entity-in-layer> intersects <bbox defined from lat/lon pairs>`

I was sure this would be easy, but my  confidence is now somewhat eroded.

Comment: The first line should read 'a QGIS virtual layer based on a Shapefile', perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your main question is how to write `WHERE` clause.

Try:

```
WHERE mbrintersects(
       mylayer.geometry, 
       st_geomfromtext('MULTIPOINT(12.3 23.4, 12.4 23.5)', 4326)
      )
```

The above example uses two points (Longitude, Latitude)=(12.3, 23.4) and (12.4, 23.5) to define your bounding box.

Comment: That is precisely what I needed, thank you! Is there a reference manual somewhere for these functions? I could not find mbrintersects in any QGIS doc, but it is in various other GIS-related docs.

Comment: @RabidMutant you are right, I cannot find it in QGIS docs. Instead, I rely on `SpatiaLite` docs [4.3.0](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html). SpatiaLite version used in QGIS can be found in the menu `Help | About`.

Comment: Thanks again! Never knew SpatiaLite existed. May be useful in my own app. Thanks again.

Comment: One more quick question: I tried Intersects instead of mbrintersects and got much fewer rows than expected (2 vs 101). Most of the regions are completely contained in the bbox. Is there a special gotcha with "intersects"?

Comment: @RabidMutant `mbrintersects` enables to determine intersection of extent. Using `intersects` means a points-to-points comparison: whether points are located at the same place. If you prefer `intersects`, then you can wrap your second argument by something like `st_envelope()`. For instance `st_envelope(st_geomfromtext('MULTIPOINT(12.3 23.4, 12.4 23.5)', 4326))`. Their output would be similar, but may not be exactly the same.

Comment: wow, ok, that's a bit counter-intuitive (to me). Is there a genuine polygon intersection? st_envelope just creates a rectangular box, and mbrintersects is rectamgular as well?

Comment: @RabidMutant yes, very much counter-intuitive (to me, too). How about `st_convexhull(st_union(st_geomfromtext('MULTIPOINT(12.3 23.4, 12.4 23.5)', 4326)))` ? (`st_union` may or may not necessary, depend on your input data). It gives you a convex hull, so it is polygon.

Comment: @RabidMutant Forgot to mention we need at least three points to create a convex hull...